# How is jmockit-coverage activated?

Tags: java, jmockit

When we testing by `JUnit` with `jmockit-coverage`, we only configure it by adding the dependency on maven `pom.xml` as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmockit-coverage</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then it will give the coverage result. So my question is how is `jmockit` coverage activated? It seems that we never run the its code but it runs.

Comment: Which version of JMockit are you using? Have you checked the [JMockit Tutorial](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html#maven) lately?

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.23</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of the `-coverage` in

```
    <artifactId>jmockit-coverage</artifactId>
```

have you tried

```
    <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
```

like [JMockit Tutorial](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Introduction.html#maven) suggests?

But maybe you have to check the configuration of your *surefire-plugin* too, see [JMocikt Tutorial](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html#maven):

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
         <!-- At least one of the following needs to be set: -->
         <coverage-output>html</coverage-output>     <!-- or: html-nocp, serial, serial-append -->
         <coverage-metrics>all</coverage-metrics>    <!-- or: line, path, data -->
         <coverage-classes>loaded</coverage-classes> <!-- or a "*" expression for class names -->
...
```